# processor features visibility to the OS

Tags: operating-system, cpu, cpu-architecture

How microprocessors manufacturers make some things visible to the software and others don't?

- for example what makes ISA, registers and register number visible and other features like cache size invisible?
- could they  choose to make other features also visible like cache size to the software?
- How do they make something visible and something not? what makes a
  feature visible to the software?

Comment: microprocessor and ISA bus and ISA device are different pieces of hardware. CPU does not control (make visible) I/O signals appearing on the bus and how the hardware devices connected to the bus respond. Operating System can control access to the hardware devices and make them invisible to user-level software because I/O instructions are `privileged`. See "16.5 PROTECTED-MODE I/O" in [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-manual-325462.pdf)

Comment: @xmojmr Umm... by ISA I meant Intruction set architecture, not Industry Standard Architecture

Comment: Some feature if visible if there's and instruction in the instruction set that allows you to use it or if there's a hardware protocol that exposes it. The architecture must be known up-front and if an instruction is not implemented by the processor then the processor throws `Invalid Opcode` exception. See table "Table 6-1. Exceptions and Interrupts" and "CHAPTER 17 PROCESSOR IDENTIFICATION AND FEATURE DETERMINATION" and "CPUID" in the above linked document. It's same as if you don't mark a symbol as public in your C code and external code can not link it and use it. What's the problem?

Comment: @xmojmr you mentioned hardware protocol, do you what kind of protocols is this? how they are implemented?

Comment: I don't understand (yet) what exactly do you need to know and why, so I'm giving you only _abstract_ blah blah. For instance the hardware protocol for finding out a CPU cache size for Intel processors documented in the above document is that caller sets register `eax=4` and issues `cpuid` instruction and CPU returns the size encoded in bits of registers `ebx`, `ecx` - for exact description see chapter "INPUT EAX = 04H: Returns Deterministic Cache Parameters for Each Level". Stack Overflow search query `cache size cpuid` can give you some sample source code

Comment: Register numbers and other ISA details are necessary for creating machine code for that CPU.  It's not something you could change without breaking binary compatibility.  It's not "visible" to software so much as being a guaranteed compile-time constant for anything that compiles to machine code (instead of Java bytecode or other intermediate representation).  Caching is "just" a performance feature.

Answer (score 1):

First, understand that "visibility" is not a boolean - there are different amounts of visibility. Some things may be defined as "always existing on every implementation" (except when there's bugs in the CPU), some things may be optional, some things may be model specific, some things may be undocumented but still visible, some things may be unintentionally visible even though nobody wants it to be (speculative execution vulnerabilities).

> for example what makes ISA, registers and register number visible and other features like cache size invisible

Ideally, an impartial organisation creates a specification (focusing only on "benefits to consumers"), then everyone (programmers, compiler developers, CPU manufacturers) work towards complying with the specification; such that all software that complies with the specification works on all CPUs that comply with the specification. In practice this mostly doesn't happen. Instead, CPU manufacturers fight amongst themselves to make their product seem better while crippling their competition (e.g. by being deliberately incompatible, polluting the opcode space, using patents to prevent competition, etc). The end result is that decisions about how things should work and how visible things should be ends up being a compromise between marketing and legalities without much consideration to "benefits to consumers" (beyond marketing hype). For a "nice" example of this, take a look at the history of "sysenter vs. syscall" on 80x86.

> could they choose to make other features also visible like cache size to the software?

Cache is always at least slightly visible (e.g. you can always write a program that uses brute-force timing techniques to auto-determine cache size). CPU manufacturers can make it more visible (e.g. adding cache parameters to `CPUID` using 3 or 4 different, incompatible and vendor specific ways to annoy everyone). In theory CPU manufacturers could also make it less visible, but that tends to break compatibility for older software so it rarely happens.

> How do they make something visible and something not? what makes a feature visible to the software?

Something is more visible if way/s to see it are described in "the official" standard (or maybe just in one of the manufacturer's manuals if there's no organisation responsible for creating an official standard). Something is less visible if there's no documented way to see it.